# [Spring][JPA] Automatic save when ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two Oracle tables `INDEX` & `USER` with relationship table between them `INDEX_USER(INDEX_ID NUMBER(8), USER_ID NUMBER(8), IN_CHARGE NUMBER(1), BACKUP NUMBER(1))`.

I represent the INDEX table like that in my Java code :

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Index {
//others attributs

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="INDEX_USER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="INDEX_ID"), joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"))
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "IN_CHARGE = 1")
private Set<User> inCharges;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="INDEX_USER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="INDEX_ID"), joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"))
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "BACKUP = 1")
private Set<User> backups;

}
```

N.B : INDEX_ID & USER_ID are the primary key of my relationship table

When I try to save a new Index with `repository.save(index);` spring try to save also my Sets in the relationship table but I don't want that.

Because :

- it's store them without the flags IN_CHARGE & BACKUP
- I can have the same User in charge and backup of in Index so it's create a primary key violation

I have tried to add CascadeType.MERGE but dosent worked for me.

I wan't use a @OneToMany relation and create entity for my relationship table. I found is more clear for me like that.

**EDIT :**
As proposed by @kaqqao. I changed my code to have a @OneToMany relationship :

```
public class IndexUser {

    @EmbeddedId
    private IndexUserPK id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "IN_CHARGE")
    private Boolean inCharge;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "BACK_UP")
    private Boolean backUp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "INDEX_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Index index;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;


}
```

and add a new method in my Index class :

```
public void addUser(User user, boolean inCharge, boolean backup){
        IndexUserPK pk = new IndexUserPK(user.getId(), this.getId());
        IndexUser indexUser= new IndexUser(pk, inCharge, backup, this, user);
        this.getIndexUsers().add(indexUser);
    }
```

But when I try to save new Index with a list of IndexUser objects that gives my this exception :

```
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-02291: violation de contrainte d'intégrité (SCHEMA.PK_INDEX_USER_FK) - clé parent introuvable
```

If someone have any idea about how to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If a relationship table has columns that are not foreign keys (it is an aggregation), it should be modeled as an entity in itself. In your case that would mean introducing an entity like:

```java
@Entity
plublic class IndexUser {

    @EmbeddedId
    IndexUserId id;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("indexId")
    Index index;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userId")
    User user;
 
    @Column
    boolean backup;
 
    @Column(name = "in_charge")
    boolean inCharge;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class IndexUserId
    implements Serializable {
 
    @Column(name = "index_id")
    Long indexId;
 
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    Long userId;

    ...

}
```

And then have `@OneToMany` relationship from both `User` and `Index` entities to `IndexUser`.

```java
@Entity
public class Index {
 
    ...
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "index")
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "...")
    Set<IndexUser> backups;
     
    ...
}
```

See this post for more info: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Or maybe [this one](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-many-to-many-association-with-additional-attributes/), if you find Vlad's canonical post a bit much.

But. If you end up finding all of JPA (and ORM in general) a bit much, see this instead: https://blog.jooq.org/the-second-best-way-to-fetch-a-spring-data-jpa-dto-projection/. I hope you find it as eye opening as I have.

Comment: Hello,
I do the modifications to work with what you proposed but I have another problem. When I try to save a new Index that contains a list of my relationship entity IndexUser. It's dosen't work and give me a parent key not found exception